# PHP vs BASH for CLI scripting?

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

I have never used PHP with CLI, but I have seen scripts running with PHP code.

I was wondering:

- Why should we use BASH, when PHP is so popular and is able to run in CLI?
- What are the pros and cons with each one?
- Should I use PHP for all CLI scripting in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still much easier to perform many common tasks in bash. Consider writing PHP equivalents for the following bash one-liners:

```bash
# remove a folder full of rubbish
rm -rf oldTrashFolder

# create an archive of files containing the word 'localhost'
tar cf backup.tar $(grep -rlw localhost ~/my-source-code)

# make a copy of a mysql database
{ echo "create database NEWDATABASE; "; mysqldump OLDDATABASE; } | mysql NEWDATABASE
```

Comment: The only right way is that one that helps you achieve your goals. So nevermind if you use PHP, Bash, Python or whatever. Just do the way it best fits for you.

Comment: I'd like to point out the ability to, in PHP, to use backtics to execute `rm -rf oldTrashFolder`. That essentially negates this entire opinion. Code in whatever you're comfortable in, imo. Also, take into consideration if your script will be in an environment where you don't want PHP installed (or you'll be moving it for quick-execution and don't ever want to install PHP simply because you chose to write it in PHP).

Answer (score 7):

Bash is more common for this type of application, simply by virtue of it being around forever. But when it comes to choosing one over the other. The language you already know is usually the better choice. Just because you will be more productive.

Comment: There is no better answer than this one

Answer (score 4):

Preference mainly.

Higher level languages (like php) have better data structures easily accessible (among other things).  However, it's pretty easy to hack together a working bash script.

So really, it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the main thing is: bash is always there on a recent unix system (its predecessors really are always there, even on ancient unixen).  Bash uses every little utility on the system, which can include PHP, Python, Ruby, AWK, Perl (those last two especially).

Consider: how do you get PHP installed?  Bunch of bash scripts and a makefile, right?  Or your OS package manager, which these days is probably Python, but used to be a bash script as well.

You can't administer unix without knowing the shell really well, nor can you write or use makefiles.  It may not be the right answer every time, but for a scripting job I always try to figure out if it can be done in bash first.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is only better in the web directory. Bash is better suited for handling command line inputs and general shell semantics, IMO.

Comment: To be honest, I'd pick python,ruby, or perl over php to write shell scripts, for similar reasons that I might pick php over bash to serve up content via HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

I think python is better than php for CLI.

If you have never used PHP, I recommend Python, because PHP was originally designed for web development to produce dynamic web pages, and for Python, It's more generous and emphasize code readability.

Comment: Python is better than PHP because it has `shutil` and `getopt` modules which simplify many CLI tasks. You need to do these things by hand for PHP.

Comment: I second the Python recommendation. If you have the misfortune of working in a Windows environment like I do, writing CLI in python is relatively transferable from one OS to another. Whereas using BASH directly is not, unless you are able to use MINGW, which I am not. The nice thing about python is the ability to integrate with the hosting OS's command line capabilities. If you need to use one liners like the above, you can easily access them from Python.

Comment: PHP was designed for web is the worst argument. It works perfectly well as a cli tool plus it has support for everything that python has, there is no need to ever use python unless you are an indentation fanatic. It is slower than php and more cryptic. As for bash, it is definitely preferred here. Use a more complex language if there is a need for it.

Answer (score 2):

For general purpose task scripting i would suggest going Bash all the way.

Bash is probably most widely spread shell and your script will be able to run on most *nix systems. By contrast PHP will not always be readily available. Of course if you don't intend to use those scripts over unfamiliar system you'll be fine with both.

That said, most standard shell commands are easier to write in bash then in php. In php you would open a subprocesses, execute shell commands through some wrapper functions or what not while in bash you would simply record your bash session in a file an made it executable. Take listing of a directory for example, in bash you simply state `ls` and in php you'd probably be using [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) which isn't fun as it sounds. Also i would imagine scandir has lot less sorting options. `grep -Ri something .` anyone?

Most of the general purpose languages can be used for shell scripting, but that doesn't mean they should be and at the end of the day it comes down to getting the job done and a matter of subjective preference.

Comment: good example with ls vs scandir:)

Answer (score -2):

I was looking into this myself as I'm current doing a upgrade a on large LMS having come across this link and another which has some result to a proformance test I thought I would add this link to [this](http://tspycher.com/2012/01/performance-test-python-perl-php-and-c/) post.
while it task is nota real world example it does show some interesting stats.

Comment: Welcome! Please read the rules before posting a question or an answer.