# PHP: copy vs ZIP extract, what is better?

Tags: php, performance, copy, extract, unzip

I want to copy a large folder with a lot of sub folders & files (~300 MB) to another folder, this task is rare.

Please tell me, what solution I should choose to have better speed & performance:

1. Zip folder first, place zipped file to a place, then unzip to destination when I need to copy.
2. Use copy normally.

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP ? You can easily do this in bash? assuming it's a linux server

Comment: well, because this task is in a script

Comment: If you have CLI access, do it there.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785155/php-vs-bash-for-cli-scripting

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will use more CPU processing power.
Option 2 will be more I/O intensive.

Depending on your server specs, one may be more efficient than the other. More information would be needed!